# Is it possible to chain pseudo classes within a :not selector?

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-class

I've gotten to the result I was looking for, but was just wondering if there is a better way to get there.
I have an unknown number of elements within a 2 column grid container `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`.
There are grid lines between all the elements, but not outside of them.
I've done this the following way:

```
.parent > * {
    padding: 1.2rem 0;

    &:not(:last-child) {
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    }

    &:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd) {
      border-bottom: none;
    }

    &:nth-child(odd) {
      border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    }
  }
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way than resetting the border styling on the second to last element if it is odd. I can't figure out why something like this isn't doing it.

```
&:not(:last-child):not(:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd)){
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

Thanks a ton.
Kind regards,
Jerome

Comment: what you have is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it in one line.

Target every even child plus every odd child that is not the second to last:

```css
.parent {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.parent > :nth-child(even), .parent > :nth-child(odd):not(:nth-last-child(2)){
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
   padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```